# Generate a DSA key pair with 2048 bit - add to the authorized_keys

Tags: unix, openssl, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-keygen

My first attempt since ssh-keygen doesn't support dsa with size of 2048 (DSA keys must be 1024 bits), was to generate one with the size of 1024 (with no password):

```
$ ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t dsa

id_dsa
id_dsa.pub
```

then used the command `ssh-copy-id` to add the key to my `authorized_keys`.

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@host
```

at the end as suggested tried the `ssh user@host` with success without being request any password.

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen

But since `1024` is not recommended and the minimal requested is 2048, tried searching using `openssl` instead that does support the `2048` for `dsa` format.

Found the following 'tutorial': https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/create-rsa-dsa-key-with-openssl how to generate the keys using openssl

```
$ openssl dsaparam -out dsaparam.pem 2048
$ openssl gendsa -out dsaprivkey.pem dsaparam.pem
```

with this two commands creates the private key in the file dsaprivkey.pem

to get the public key

```
$ openssl dsa -in dsaprivkey.pem -outform DER -pubout -out dsapubkey.der
```

Now my problem was how to integrate this key's into to my `authorized_keys` the public and the private was already in `/.ssh` folder that generated directly.

At this point not sure if this is the correct approach since to me openssl is used more in the context of generating certificates to install and permit the HTTPS communication and not much to do with authentication using the public and private keys as openssh...

but still tried using as [example](http://dmitrypukhov.pro/adding-ssh-keys-to-authorized_keys/) to convert the pem file into a public key using the command suggested

```
ssh-keygen -y -f dsaprivkey.pem > dsa_pubkey.pub
```

and with this public key `dsa_pubkey.pub` could use with `ssh-copy-id`, but still was in doubt if .pem file should be the private key as the one used or should it be public key instead but again read somewhere that dsaprivkey.pem should in fact contains both the keys

```
$ openssl dsa -in dsaprivkey.pem -outform DER -pubout -out dsapubkey.der
```

that makes some sense since the public key was generated using the private as input.

after the step `ssh-copy-id`

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i ~/.ssh/dsa_pubkey.pub user@host
```

but now the ssh user@host requests the password so it means its not working with this new dsa 2048 keys.

Can some give some light to what steps are wrong or if this is even possible?? since its seems to me to be redundant to use `openssl` to generate the dsa 2048 keys just to later on convert using `ssh-keygen` that doesn't support 2048 in the first place...

---

Thanks for the answers, gona follow as sugested here and use the `rsa` that is already was what was inclined to use from the beginning...

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an RSA key?  (And this seems relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29309/is-the-use-of-dsa-keys-a-security-risk)

Comment: OpenSSH can (and before 7.8 usually did) use OpenSSL format _private_ key files except for ed25519 but the OpenSSH _public_ key format is different from OpenSSL's so any `opensssl {pkey
|algo} -pubout` will not work; you do need `ssh-keygen -y`. But this is not programming or development

Comment: Also, none of the formats generated by OpenSSH _or_ OpenSSL is PPK, so naming such a file .ppk is misleading, confusing and likely to cause mistakes. If you want a suffix, .pr[i]v or (more generic) .pem is suitable, or maybe something more specific about the format like .ossl/.trad/.old or ossh/.new as applicable, but you don't usually need that.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AndrewHenle there isn't a specific reason since that would be my prefered way and seems the only and correct way from the answers here, just it was a requirement for project but seems whover made it a requirement didn't know much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by @dave_thompson_085, OpenSSH *ssh* and *sshd* do support all DSA sizes allowed by OpenSSL/libcrypto, but *ssh-keygen* can only generate ssh-dss keys with 1024 bits. So the reason why the 2048-bit ssh-dss key didn't work for you may be because it was disabled in the configuration of *ssh* or *sshd*. @dave_thompson_085 also wrote: OpenSSH 7.0 up by default disables ssh-dss for all sizes, and larger (186-3) sizes still use SHA-1 which is no longer considered secure.

So may may want to run `ssh -vvv user@host`, and post the output to your question. It will reveal which key is used, which keys *ssh* offers and which keys *sshd* supports.

You may want to use ssh-ed25519 keys (always 128 bits, secure) or ssh-rsa2 keys (any number of bits, [at least 3072 bits](https://goteleport.com/blog/comparing-ssh-keys/) is recommended for good security) or ssh-rsa keys (with SHA-1) for OpenSSH *sshd* older than 8.8 (ssh-rsa disabled by default in OpenSSH 8.8) instead with OpenSSH. See also reasons [why ssh-dss keys are insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys).

Comment: _This is incorrect._ `ssh-keygen` will only _generate_ 1024, but `ssh` and `sshd` do implement all DSA sizes allowed by OpenSSL/libcrypto -- however 7.0 up by default disables ssh-dss for all sizes, and larger (186-3) sizes still use SHA1 which is no longer considered secure. Note OpenSSH 8.8 up by default disables ssh-rsa (with SHA1) and only enables rsa-sha2-# which use the same RSA key (even 1024-bit!) with SHA2. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146379/does-ssh-support-dsa-with-2048-bit-keys .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thank you, I've updated my answer based on your comment.